# Deciphering descriptions for momentary switches

Tags: switches, dpdt

While shopping for momentary switches for a DIY project I'm working on, I've come across some descriptions I don't fully understand. These are all related to DPDT switches.

Examples:
ON-OFF-(ON),
(ON)-OFF-(ON),
ON-OFF-ON,
ON-NONE-ON,
ON-NULL-ON

Can anyone explain the significance of the parentheses around "on" in the first two examples? Also, what is the difference between "off", "none", and "null" in the last three examples?

Thanks in advance for any information.

Comment: I think the parens mean spring-loaded momentary.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We don't know what they mean as each website can describe the same thing differently, and the only place you can see what is really meant is the manufacturer data sheet for the switch. Please list the switches and provide links to manufacturer data sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses indicate a momentary position - if you move the switch to that position it will automatically return to the OFF position when you release it.

I would say that the handle of an ON-OFF-ON switch has three positions, while an ON-NONE/NULL-ON switch handle only has the two end positions - it has no center position.